# Maintainance of boites in CTAN

Tags: package-writing, ctan

I have done some fixes and enhancements to the [`boites` LaTeX package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/boites) and I would like to have them integrated to the version in CTAN.

In the last time I have contacted the current maintainer (on Apr 19 2012), he answered that he no longer maintains this package, but since it is free software, I can modify it.

So I want to know how to update the package in CTAN with my changes.

**More information about the package:**

At the beginning of the [boites.dtx](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/boites/boites.dtx) file there is the following text:

```
%% Copyright (c) Markus Kohm <komascript at gmx.info>, 2009 
%%               (boites.dtx only)
%% Copyright (c) Susan Dittmar <Susan.Dittmar@gmx.de>, 2009 
%%               (english translation)
%% Copyright (c) Vincent Zoonekynd <zoonek@math.jussieu.fr>, 1998-1999 
%%               (boites.sty)
%%
%% This work was derived from Susan Dittmar's translated version of
%% Vincent Zoonekynd's boites.sty.
%%
%% This file is distributed unter the same license like the orignal
%% boites.sty from March 1999: The GNU Public Licence.
%%
%% This file is not maintained!
```

Comment: Do you have a copy of this information from him? CTAN will want to see it before they'll accept a change.

Comment: @JosephWright yes, I have the email messages we exchanged.

Answer (score 9):

Having a 'free' license means that software can be modified by people other than the original author, with the exact rules of course depending on the license involved. However, CTAN are free to accept or otherwise contributions independent of this. In particular, they tend toward the position that there is one 'official' version of each package, something that is important in the (La)TeX world. As such, some 'proof' is normally required when 'taking over' a package that this is the 'official' version.

Typically, an e-mail or similar from the original author staying that a new person can take over is acceptable as proof. In cases where this is not possible, for example picking up an 'unmaintained' [LPPL](http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt) package, a link to the 'public notice' for the take-over would be the normal proof.

Comment: Of course, asking them is perhaps the shortest way to get an answer!

Comment: In `boites.dtx` it is explicitly said that the file is unmaintained. I have the email message from the current maintainer as described in the question. Is that enough to apply for the maintainer position of the package on ctan, and upload a new version?

Comment: @Romildo I would think it almost certainly is: in the [upload form](http://www.ctan.org/upload/) for CTAN there is a box for notes to the team, so you can explain things there.

Comment: Now I am maintaining the `boites` package.